# How can I flick an object so it moves indefinitely with velocity depending on force of flick?

Tags: java, android, object

I have a circle on a graph, and I want to be able to flick it and have it move indefinitely and wrap around the screen as it goes. The circle, or ball is how I coded it, is a view. Right now I just have a circle I can touch and drage, via this code:

```
          //Creates view for ball
           FrameLayout flView = (FrameLayout) v;
           flView.setPaddingRelative(0, padding, 0, 0);

           //Creates new ball
           ball = new Ball(findViewById(R.id.main_view).getContext(), x, y, 10,padding);


           switch(event.getAction()){   

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:       
                    flView.removeAllViews();
                    flView.addView(ball);

                    break;


                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:       

                    flView.removeAllViews();
                    flView.addView(ball);

                    break;


           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do.  Essentially I'd measure the startPosition (x,y) of the ball, and the time the user first taps the screen, ball, whatever.  Then as the user moves their finger across the screen I'd calculate the velocity given the ball's current (x,y) and time.  Then I'd calculate the pixels / ms it was moving.  Once they pick up their figure just keep adding the X,Y velocity to the ball's position, and mod that by the screen size so it'll wrap.

```
// Don't keep adding and removing the ball from the view.  
// Just add it once on startup, then you can move the ball's 
// position when the user clicks on the screen.
flView.addView(ball);

switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                ball.x = event.x;
                ball.y = event.y;
                int lastPositionX = ball.x
                int lastPositionY = ball.y
                long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                ball.velocity.x = (lastPositionX - startPositionX) / (lastTime - startTime);
                ball.velocity.y = (lastPositionY - startPositionY) / (lastTime - startTime);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:       
                ball.x = event.x;
                ball.y = event.y;
                ball.velocity.x = 0.0;
                ball.velocity.y = 0.0;
                startPositionX = ball.x;
                startPositionY = ball.y;
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                break;
       }
```

I'm not sure what that code you provided really does, but the Move section listener looks bad so I removed the code I think looked wrong.  Now it simply moves the ball to where the person touched.  After that you'll have to figure out how to animate the scene.  Essentially all you have to do is this:

```
ball.x = (ball.velocity.x + ball.x) % screenSize;
ball.y = (ball.velocity.y + ball.y) % screenSize;
```

Comment: My code is all in an onTouch method. the ACTION_MOVE case can't see startTime, startPositionX, or startPositionY, what should I do?

Comment: You'll have to move the definition of some of those variables up and out of this method.  Things that have to persist past a single execution of that method will become instance variables.  I think startPositionX, startPositionY, and startTime will have to be instance variables on the Listener class.

Answer (score 0):

For AndEngine there is an onFlick method you can use. I believe it measures the direction and velocity. All that's left are any conversions you need to use, and then animation. I haven't used the method for awhile, and I forget the actual code, but I'm sure you can find it online. Sorry I couldn't give you any code.